# Variable Initialization in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

In the Fortran book by Nyhoff, on p. 51, it is stated that a variable can be initialized by a "constant expression". However, Nyhoff doesn't seem to say what exactly a constant expression is.

Question 1: Can a variable be initialized by a user-defined function? Ex: `real :: myreal=myrealfunc(4.0)` (It is possible for a variable to be initialized by an intrinsic function.)

Question 2: This is not directly related to Question 1. Consider a case when a main program does not `use` a specific module, but one of the subprograms `use` this module. If a variable is part of this module, does it get initialized at the beginning of the execution of the main program, or until the subprogram (that `use` the module) is invoked?

References, if available, would also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1: No, a variable cannot be initialised by a user-defined function.  R505 (of the Fortran 2008 draft standard I have in front of me) says that a variable can only be initialised by a *constant-expr*. Para 7.1.12.1 of the same document defines *constant-expr* and includes the words *It is an expression in which each operation is intrinsic*.

Answer 2: The `use`-d variable is only accessible inside the scope(s) in which it is `use`-d. When it is actually initialised is a moot point.  I suspect that it is *processor-dependent* (as that term is defined at clause 1.3.114 of the standard).

I also suspect that compilers will initialise at program start up.  Although the standard doesn't require it, scarcely even hints at it, initialisation expressions are probably, in practice, computable by the compiler.  I guess you would be able to figure out the behaviour of your processor by examining the memory consumption of a program which initialises a large variable.  You won't be able to simply print or otherwise examine a variable during execution when the variable is not in scope.

Of course variables which are initialised acquire the `save` attribute which means that their values are saved across invocations of their enclosing scope.

A reference in the standard to validate this answer escapes me right now.

Comment: For 1: Thanks. I'm accustomed to MATLAB classes, which do allow you to initialize class variables using a user-defined function. So for Fortran I guess I will create a separate setter function to call to set the value of the module variables. For 2: Yes, with the answer of Q1 in mind, it no longer matters when these variables are initialized and Q2 is now moot.

Comment: Just for the records, because this question is tagged with fortran90, I should mention the quoted material also appears in the Fortran 90 standard,  with which gfortran (the compiler I'm using) is fully compliant.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question I'll take the same starting point as [High Performance Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27287670/3157076), paragraph 7.1.12.1, but interpret it slightly differently.  I'll come to the same conclusion.

Yes, each operation in a constant expression must be intrinsic, but a reference to a user-defined function as in the question isn't an operation.  It is, instead, a *primary* and a list of allowed primaries follows in that paragraph.

That said, from the allowed cases for a primary in the sub-paragraphs that follow (4--8), each function reference must be to an intrinsic function.